# how to customize react material ui next component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using [Material UI](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) [next branch](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/next) i want to use the table component and i want to change the style of the [TableHead](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/next/src/Table/TableHead.js) Component.

My idea was to wrap the TableHead with MyTableHead and add my own style to override the current style.

my code(based on this [Composition](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/composition)):

```
import React from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'
import {
    TableHead,
} from 'material-ui/Table';

const styles = {
   th: {        
        fontSize:'20px',        
    },    
}

const _MyTableHead = (props) => {
    return (
        <TableHead className={props.classes.th} {...props}>
            {props.children}
        </TableHead>
    );
};
_MyTableHead.muiName = 'TableHead'    
const MyTableHead = injectSheet(styles)(_MyTableHead);


export {MyTableHead}
```

This does not work:
1. my style is overrided by the original style
2. i get an error in the browser js console:

> Warning: Unknown props `sheet`, `classes` on  tag. Remove these
>   props from the element. For details, see
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html
>       in thead (created by TableHead)
>       in TableHead (at table.js:15)
>       in _MyTableHead (created by Jss(_MyTableHead))

I think i am not doing it right, any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

The way to customize components in the next branch is not documented yet.
This is how it can be done:

```
import React from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {createMuiTheme} from 'material-ui/styles/theme'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides:{
    MuiButton:{
      root:{
        fontSize: 20,
      }
    }
  }  
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // MuiThemeProvider takes the theme as a property and passed it down the hierarchy
    // using React's context feature.
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <Button raised>Default</Button>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example Class from MUINext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3dO.png)

Material UI regenerates new classes upon render, so you will never be able to override any one class with a preset class.

Their class name will look something like `MuiRoot-tableHead-23`. The last number is random.
Find the specific class that is overriding your class, and then use

```
[class*=MuiRoot-tableHead]{
your css settings
}
```

If you have a theme file already setup, I'd suggest going with what yossi said. Otherwise, you can manually override it using this method.